# NCMBを使ったPUSH通知の実機テストの挙動について

Tags: ios, push-notification

iosのPUSH通知のテストを実機を用いて行うと、ケーブルでつないでいる時と外した時で呼び出されるメソッドのタイミングが異なるのですが、これは通常の挙動なのでしょうか？？

Answer (score 0):

おそらく、ケーブルでつないでいる時と外した時というのはフォアグラウンドorバックグラウンドという意味だと思い回答します。
フォアグラウンドかバックグラウンドかによって、呼ばれるメソッドは異なります。
https://qiita.com/sxo/items/eab3e2bc9febb57cf37f#%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE3-push%E9%80%9A%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%92%E5%8F%97%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

> // 通常のPush通知の受信
>   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
>       NSLog(@"pushInfo: %@", [userInfo description]); }
>
> // BackgroundFetchによるバックグラウンドの受信
>   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
>   fetchCompletionHandler:(void
>   (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
>       NSLog(@"pushInfo in Background: %@", [userInfo description]);
>       completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData); }